# Pandas on_bad_lines = 'skip' not doing anything

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a csv file where there is one row with an extra column (for school) and I'm using on_bad_lines = 'skip'

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', usecols = ["technique used","efficacy of technique used","education level", "XoviD21 result"], on_bad_lines='skip')
```

[Output of the line with an extra column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Eegi.png)

this appears to not be being run as the row is in the dataset, wondering if it has to do with the way I've used usecols?

thanks

Comment: "this appears to not be being run as the row is in the dataset" What does this mean? Please read [mre] and make it possible for us to see the problem, by showing: a small sample input file (`.csv` is a plain text format, which you can show as text, formatted like code), enough code to read and display the file; an explanation of what you expect to see as the resulting `df`, and what you do see instead.

Comment: "wondering if it has to do with the way I've used usecols?" What exactly is the goal? I assume you want to skip rows that have unrecognized data, even if they also have all of those columns? Another possible approach I can think of is to load the entire data (skipping bad rows), and then just select the columns with the usual slicing approach.

Comment: You're right.  It is `usecols`.  Pulls in the columns defined in `usecols` and then ignores any extra column - is I believe how it works.  So then doesn't look like a bad line.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel edited, and the goal is to just remove the row which has extra columns. I tried your idea and it still isn't removing the bad row

Comment: Are you sure the line is actually "bad"? Again, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @jch even when I use this without usecols, it still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3):

`usecols` is defining the columns to include.  Everything else is ignored.  So the bad line error is never triggered:

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO(
'''A,B,C
11,21,31
12,22,32
13,23,33,43  # Bad Line
14,24,34
15,25,35'''
)
```

Default processing - bad line is detected:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv)

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 4
```

With `usecols` the extra data in the bad line is ignored:

```
sim_csv.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv, usecols=['A','B','C'])
df

    A   B   C
0  11  21  31
1  12  22  32
2  13  23  33
3  14  24  34
4  15  25  35
```

Without `usecols` and with `on_bad_lines='skip'` the bad line is dropped:

```
sim_csv.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv, on_bad_lines='skip')
df

    A   B   C
0  11  21  31
1  12  22  32
2  14  24  34
3  15  25  35
```